# Calculate $E(Y)$ where $Y=X^{1.5}$

Tags: probability, integration, statistics, probability-distributions, gamma-function

Let $X$ be a rv which is $Exp(\lambda=2)$.

The pdf of $X$ is given by $f_X(x)=2e^{-2x}, x\geq 0$ (and $0$ otherwise).

We define $Y=X^{1.5}$ and ask $E(Y)$.

It does not look like the moment generating function can help me here. So, instead I evaluate the integral:

$$2\int^{\infty}_{0}e^{-2x}x^{1.5}dx$$

I know the **Gamma** function is given by: $$\int_{0}^{\infty}x^{\alpha-1}e^{-x}dx$$ but I have $e^{-2x}$ in my original integral. So I don't think this can help me either.

My question is the following:

1) If I were to evaluate the integral, it seems very messy by parts. Is there a simple way to evaluate the integral?

2) Is there a simpler way to solve the question that I am missing?

Comment: Why not variable change $y:=2x$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just make a change of variables $u = 2x$, so that ${\rm d}x = {\rm d} u / 2$ and

$$
2\int_0^{+\infty}x^{3/2}e^{-2x}{\rm d}x = 2^{-3/2} \int_0^{+\infty}u^{3/2}e^{-u}{\rm d}u = 2^{-3/2} \int_0^{+\infty}u^{5/2 - 1}e^{-u}{\rm d}u = 2^{-3/2}\Gamma(5/2)
$$

You can further simplify this by using $\Gamma(5/2) = 3\pi^{1/2}/4$

$$
\mathbb{E}[X^{3/2}] = 3\cdot2^{-7/2}\pi^{1/2}
$$

Comment: Sometimes it's the simplest things you miss. Thank you

Comment: On a second thought, do you know if this contradicts the monotonicity of expectation? Basically it says that if $X \leq Y$, then $E[X]\leq E[Y]$. We have that $X\leq X^{1.5}$, but $E[X]=1/\lambda = 1/2$, so this does not hold, as $E[X^{1.5}]\approx 0.47$

Comment: @KSplitX It doesn't violate it because $X>Y$ for $X<1$, but $X<Y$ for $X>1$, so the condition $X\leq Y$ is not satisfied